# Changing android signing key password

Tags: android, code-signing

Does anybody know how (and if) you can change the password used to sign android builds?

We have a live app, but want to change the signing password. The problem is that we don't want to force our users to reinstall the app (if we use a new key users won't be able to install the new build as an update to the original app).

I've looked all over the android documentation, but have been unable to find anything even related to the subject (except for making a new key...).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Actually, this is possible:

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore my.keystore
```

Comment: Even though I don't need the fix anymore I'm sure you're a hero for tons of developers! :D

Comment: @Thomas Vervest - this is **NOT** an answer to your question.  What this will at best do is change the password which would be used in subsequent compilations made from the development configuration on which it is run.  It will do nothing to help your problem of the existing installations under the old key.

Comment: Please explain, does changing the password change the signing key (making it a "new" key)?

Comment: No, changing the password does not make it a new key -- it just changes the access to the enclosed key inside the keystore.

Answer (score 20):

You can change the `key` password , if you have the old password. What you need to run is the following command :

```
keytool -keypasswd -alias "key_alias" -keypass "old_pass" -new "new_pass" -keystore "your_keystore_path"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.  It is the signing key that identifies you as the original author and not an imposter.  The "how do I recover my lost key" question comes up frequently, and the only answer is to start over with a new application.

If you still have the original signing key, you could release an update to your application which exports user data used by your program, and then release a new app under a new key which can import it, so at least they'd be able to keep their data.  Your migration update under the old key could even use an intent to send the the user to the market download page for the new application.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case... Ah well, I guess we'll just have to do something like that then. Thank you for your answer and for your ideas on how to work around the problem.

Comment: @Chris I don't agree. The private key is stored in an encrypted file called a "KeyStore", and the password everybody use to sign APKs is actually not the private key's password: it's only the password that can decrypt the this KeyStore file so that you can access your private key. If you know this password, you can easily access your private key, and protect it with a new password for your KeyStore (see other answers based on `keytool`). And changing the password does not make it a new key. So the app is fine and so are the app users.